# Quarkus Reactive Rest: how to throw NotFoundException for 404 response?

Tags: quarkus-reactive

I have a basic Reactive Rest endpoint which should return existing Account or 404 if Account not found:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public CompletionStage<Account> get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return accountProvider
        .get(id)
        .thenApply(maybeAccount -> maybeAccount.orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new));
}
```

AccountProvider defined like this:

```
public interface AccountProvider {
    CompletableFuture<Optional<Account>> get(String id);
}
```

I was expecting Quarkus to handle NotFoundException and return a response with 404 status code without having exception in app log. However such implementation returns response with 500 status code and 404 error in app log.

What is the correct way of throwing NotFoundException?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must add an ExceptionMapper to capture the `NotFoundException` and turn it into one Response with the 404 status.

So when you throw one `NotFoundException`, which extends `ClientErrorException`, that on its turn extends `WebApplicationException`, your application will return a Response with the `404` status.

One possibility is to add it to your resource class or globally to your project.

### ExceptionMapper example to your resource class

```java
    @Provider
    public static class ErrorMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

        @Inject
        ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to handle request", exception);

            int code = 500;
            if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
                code = ((WebApplicationException) exception).getResponse().getStatus();
            }

            ObjectNode exceptionJson = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
            exceptionJson.put("exceptionType", exception.getClass().getName());
            exceptionJson.put("code", code);

            if (exception.getMessage() != null) {
                exceptionJson.put("error", exception.getMessage());
            }

            return Response.status(code)
                    .entity(exceptionJson)
                    .build();
        }

    }
```

### Complete class example

```java
package org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache.repository;

import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import io.quarkus.panache.common.Sort;

@Path("repository/fruits")
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class FruitRepositoryResource {

    @Inject
    FruitRepository fruitRepository;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FruitRepositoryResource.class.getName());

    @GET
    public List<Fruit> get() {
        return fruitRepository.listAll(Sort.by("name"));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Fruit getSingle(Long id) {
        Fruit entity = fruitRepository.findById(id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Fruit with id of " + id + " does not exist.", 404);
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
        return entity;
    }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    public Response create(Fruit fruit) {
        if (fruit.id != null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Id was invalidly set on request.", 422);
        }

        fruitRepository.persist(fruit);
        return Response.ok(fruit).status(201).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Transactional
    public Fruit update(Long id, Fruit fruit) {
        if (fruit.name == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Fruit Name was not set on request.", 422);
        }

        Fruit entity = fruitRepository.findById(id);

        if (entity == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Fruit with id of " + id + " does not exist.", 404);
        }

        entity.name = fruit.name;

        return entity;
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    @Transactional
    public Response delete(Long id) {
        Fruit entity = fruitRepository.findById(id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Fruit with id of " + id + " does not exist.", 404);
        }
        fruitRepository.delete(entity);
        return Response.status(204).build();
    }

    @Provider
    public static class ErrorMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

        @Inject
        ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to handle request", exception);

            int code = 500;
            if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
                code = ((WebApplicationException) exception).getResponse().getStatus();
            }

            ObjectNode exceptionJson = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
            exceptionJson.put("exceptionType", exception.getClass().getName());
            exceptionJson.put("code", code);

            if (exception.getMessage() != null) {
                exceptionJson.put("error", exception.getMessage());
            }

            return Response.status(code)
                    .entity(exceptionJson)
                    .build();
        }

    }
}
```

### Credits for the examples

The examples were copied from the Quarkus Quick-starts project:

- https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts
- https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/hibernate-orm-panache-quickstart/src/main/java/org/acme/hibernate/orm/panache/repository/FruitRepositoryResource.java

### NotFoundException

The NotFoundException class will pass a `404` in the constructor:

```java
public class NotFoundException extends ClientErrorException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6820866117511628388L;

    /**
     * Construct a new "not found" exception.
     */
    public NotFoundException() {
        super(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND); // 404
    }
```

### ClientErrorException

```java
public class ClientErrorException extends WebApplicationException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4101970664444907990L;

    /**
     * Construct a new client error exception.
     *
     * @param status client error status. Must be a {@code 4xx} status code.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the status code is {@code null} or is not from
     *                                  {@link javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.Family#CLIENT_ERROR} status code
     *                                  family.
     */
    public ClientErrorException(Response.Status status) {
        super((Throwable) null, validate(Response.status(status).build(), Response.Status.Family.CLIENT_ERROR));
    }
```